# Drupal node saves/edits

Tags: php, drupal

I want to do this very particular thing with my node. It seems simple, it may be difficult.

There are two users, moderators and registered.

Moderators and Registered users can both edit nodes.

When a moderator edits a node, changes are made on that node and those changes are saved.

When a registered user edits a node, the edit form loads exactly as if they are a moderator, but when they save the node, a new node is created and the old node is left unchanged.

Is this a possibility with Drupal's core.  It seems like something that should be easy, but it is looking more and more like the only solution is to do a hacky fix with the core, something I have been told never to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hack the core - drupal has nice feature called hooks.

First, you have to create your module. Not hard thing to do...just google about it, but basically:

https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7

Then, in your module file add your hook function. I.e.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7

When you register you function as hook_node_presave (by giving it exact name) your function will be called before node in any type is saved. So inside that function you can check who the user is, what role he has, what content type is being saved currently and what should you do next.

If it's a moderator - don't do anything.

But if it's a registered user create new node here, by using data provided in $node variable. And then cancel current node saving:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41340/prevent-node-from-being-saved